# Can a European bank mandate employees to have a deposit account into which salary is paid

Tags: european-union, banking, salary

Is this allowed under European law to mandate employees to open a local (i.e. same name) bank deposit account and claim salary will only be paid into that account internally?

I suppose it must be since I am aware of at least 2 banks operating this practice today. But it would be nice with clarification.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the bank also the employer here?

Comment: Yes. I should add the word its.. can a European bank mandate its employees to...

Comment: Is there any reason that it wouldn't be allowed to do so of which you are aware? Ultimately money paid to you is going to come from the employer's bank account one way or the other. The fact that is comes out of a designated sub-account with your name on it shouldn't make a difference as long as you are free to immediately transfer the funds to a bank of your choice or a postal account or cash if you are bothered to do so.

Comment: Also worth noting that the vast majority of legislation on issues like this will be at the national rather than the European level. It is likely that it is not uniform among member states if some of them prohibit this practice.